# Quick way to show that the n-th composite function for a $x$ given will be equal to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \cap [0, 1]$.

Let's consider the following function:

$f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ so that $x \mapsto 2x$ if $x \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $x \mapsto 2(1 - x)$ otherwise.

It is easy to show that for all $x \in [0, 1]$, $f(x) \in [0, 1]$.
But, for some $x$, if you compose $f$ as much time as you want, you will not be able to reach $0$. Whereas, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 0$, and we can find as much numbers that will reach $0$ by solving the equations $f(x) = 1$, and so on.

Is there a quick way to show that, for a $x$ given, this number will reach $0$ after a certain number $n$ of compositions, that is $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, f^n(x) = 0$.

As a non-trivial example, $\dfrac{2015}{2^{2015}}$ will reach $0$ eventually, in a general manner, $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ will reach $0$.

Comment: These are linear operations, so for any $x\notin\mathbb Q$, it will never reach $0$ in a finite amount of compositions.

Comment: @SimpleArt Could you explain why? I'm not familiar with properties of linear operations, sorry.

Comment: For every $x\notin\mathbb Q$, it is easy enough to see that $f(x)\notin\mathbb Q$.  On the other hand, $0\in\mathbb Q$, so $f(x)\ne0$.  Try $x=\pi/4$ for example.

Comment: @SimpleArt I can understand why $2x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, but why $1 - x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ when $x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Assume that $1-x$ is of the form $a/b$.  Can you then prove that $x$ must be of the form $a/b$?  If $x$ is not of that form, that it necessarily cannot be rational.

Comment: @SimpleArt I understand better now, because we would have : $x = \frac{b - a}{b}$ or something like this, thus $x$ cannot be rational.

Comment: Yeah, basically.  The last bit is to prove that if $x$ is rational, then $1-x$ must also be rational, but if not, then $1-x$ cannot be rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $f(x)=0$, then $x=0,1$.  Let's assume $x=1$, since $x=0$ is trivial.

Now note the following:

$f(x)=1\implies x=\frac12$

$f(x)=\frac12\implies x=\frac14,\frac34$

$f(x)=\frac14,\frac34\implies x=\frac18,\frac38,\frac58,\frac78$

$f(x)=\frac18,\frac38,\frac58,\frac78\implies x=\frac1{16},\frac3{16},\dots$

Now, this is only conjecture, but it appears to be the case that if $x=\frac{2n+1}{2^k}$, where $k,n\in\mathbb N$ and $0<x<1$, then after exactly $k+1$ compositions, you will have $0$.  If $x=\frac{2n}{2^k}$, notice the fraction simplifies, and so simplify until you've found the form $x=\frac{2n+1}{2^k}$.

Since we've created these numbers directly from the assumption that $f^n(x)=0$, there exist no other numbers such that this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not phrased well. I knew about these numbers, I wanted to know if we could predict if such a number wouldn't reach 0 or if it would, in how many steps?

Comment: @Raito Sorry for the late response, I've updated my answer to be more fitting.

Comment: Fascinating! How would you prove that *exactly* after $k + 1$ compositions, we would get $0$ ?

Comment: @Raito Induction.  If $x=\frac{2n+1}{2^k}$, prove that $f(x)=\frac{2a+1}{2^{k-1}}$.